# Is Stack Exchange linked to How360?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that some of the questions posted from Stack Exchange also appeared from [How360](http://how360.org/). Also, when i googled [one of my questions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14992/was-hiyori-based-on-kaai-yuki), a [link from How360](http://how360.org/anime/14992/was-hiyori-based-on-kaai-yuki) containing the same exact question also appears. Is Stack Exchange, by chance, linked to How360? Are these sites run by same admins?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no direct connection between Stack Exchange and How360.

The content posted on Stack Exchange sites is licensed as [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) (see the footer).

That means that anyone can reuse the content, so long as they attribute it as we require.

You will note that at the bottom of each page on How360, they link back to the post, the asker and those who answered. Thus, following our attribution guidelines (whether that's "prominent" enough or not is subjective).

Comment: @Gao - can you link to such an example? As for their purpose - you should ask them.

Comment: @Gao - yes, possibly due to newness (though that shouldn't be the case - they should attribute it immediately) - that has an answer, so that doesn't seem to be a factor.

Comment: @Gao - I've raised this internally, so the people who deal with non-compliance will see it.